# How would a city be structured if the inhabitants did not have houses?

Tags: fantasy-races, cities

Some sapient species, unlike humans, do not see the need to erect housing or beds to sleep in. They still have access to the art of construction for other purposes such as storerooms, forts, and offices, but rarely use it to make anything solely to protect their own bodies from the outdoors or in fact for any purpose that does not require a solid enclosure

Other than this, the species in question are functionally human. The technology level is around modern day

What sort of structure would a city of these species typically have? In particular I am asking about a big city into which food and resources are shipped in from elsewhere

Comment: Where do they keep their personal property? A house is not just for sleeping, it is also for storing personal effects that are not currently in use.

Comment: Do they use blankets, pillows, and mats? Or do they all just klunk down on the pavement?

Comment: Form follows function - you need to tell us how this society functions.  Do people sleep at their workplaces, or go outside and sleep in the street or what?  Where do they keep their personal possessions?  Where do they bathe?  Where do they prepare their food and eat?

Comment: I'm trying to fathom a logical reason why you would have a fort, but no house. Since a Fort functionally performs the same as a house, only for a city, instead of a family l

Comment: @TheDemonLord no it does not. A fort is a defensive structure whose primary function is defence, while a house is a habitat.

Comment: I'd probably concentrate on what else we use our homes for other than sleeping and how this could be replaced, for example: as a source of clean water, as a place to store and prepare food, a place to store clothes, dress and undress, as a source of electricity and network connection, and then there's the lavatorial arrangements. How exactly these are done will determine what your city looks like much more than just sleeping.

Comment: VTC:Opinion-Based. This is opinion-based and violates the book rule. Worse, you have modern-day technology without one of the most fundamental problems to solve that drives technology, housing and construction, which makes this a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609).

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm guessing this species is humanoid but really modeled more after, say, I dunno, armadillos or something, and when they get tired they just lay down wherever they are and fall asleep, being basically invulnerable to environmental threats? And the question is "what would this do to their city designs"? Don't answer in comments -- update the question with more details. "Functionally human" adds confusion, I think, because functionally human beings would not be able to do this. Humanoid armadillos probably could.

Comment: @Bartors - let me put it this way: A fort defends you against your peers, a house defends you against *nature* - the essence is to provide a safe and secure area with a barrier between you and *thing*.

Comment: @TheDemonLord is correct. There's little semantic difference between defending against another tribe, nature... or your neighbor. The first time you have something you don't want somebody else to have (like a really good shovel or a bag full of money) the idea of housing is born (you build a warehouse to protect your trade goods but don't think that sleeping there to better defend it is a good idea?). The premise of the question is remarkably hard to work with because the technological conditions seem to mandate the existence of housing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Viva la Difference

In my own world, there are people that would fit this description. They don't need constructed dwellings and don't make them. If they were functionally modern humans, they, like your proposed people, would zone their cities and towns much like we humans do. There would be Commercial, Industrial, Recreational, Waste Treatment, and Right-of-Way as basic zones.

The only thing missing is Residential zones. A large city would largely be ordered in much the same way a large human city is arranged. You'd have areas where people go to do their jobs, be it some sort of craft or workshop or factory setting or some kind of shop or restaurant or office workplace.

Your cities would still have churches and parks and schools and waste facilities and town garages and streets and so forth. People who don't use housing of any kind are not only relatively impervious to weather and climate, but also very likely have a much more detached relationship to personal property. They likely don't have collections of things, likely keep and use only minimal amounts of clothing, tools, decorative objects and the like. Probably don't own or use private motor vehicles. They are also more likely to live in harmony with their neighbours, less likely to steal, damage, or destroy other people's property and locations.

If they're like my people, yours will likely build, at a minimum, a mathom house. This is simply a large semi-communal structure, much like a combination between a self-storage facility and an antique or second-hand shop. This is where you put the stuff you're not using at the moment. Your people probably have these scattered throughout their cities, where people tend to work or sleep. They also most likely construct many more public access structures than we do. We build libraries to keep publicly owned books. Your people probably also construct and use "libraries" that have communally owned useful things like tools, musical instruments, gardening supplies, and the like.

These mathom houses might exist in the context of a large shared community centre. Kind of like a "town center" arrangement, there would be a mathom house, a library, an entertainment centre, schools and so forth all connected.

The end result would look like a much more decentralised city. In stead of a huge central area of concentrated commercial and industrial activity, you'd have smaller areas of industry, commerce, and mathom complexes interspersed by "open" areas where people sleep. These might act somewhat like neighbourhoods in an older city: relatively local, relatively self-contained.

Since your people are "modern", they probably do engage in industries that pose risks to the environment or are in some way odious. Waste management, heavy industry like steel works, mining, chemical plants and so forth. Your people probably don't want to sleep on the roof of local trash and recycling centre! So I suspect that this segment of the population will likely make use of some kind of communal transport --- be it a tram or trolley.

Some people might sleep on the roof of their factory, or in a cosy green space between the pizza parlour and the reading room. Still others might sleep in sleeping park, a nice quiet place set a little away from the hustle bustle of the working areas. Culturally, these people would probably be much more community and locality oriented.

Since you mention food, I'll touch on farms. These will be little different than any farm you'd see in a human countryside. There will be pastures and fallow fields, herds and flocks of livestock, barns and paddocks and silos. The only thing missing is the farm house! You'd likely find the people who do the farming either sleep in a nice garden area on the farm or in some cosy area in the local village. Of course, farmers need to transport their produce to markets, so standard vehicles like lorries would be in use to handle those logistics.

Answer (score 2):

**Eco-friendly city with lack of personal property**

Aka living on the trees. The poor species experience psychical discomfort from being under a roof instead of clear sky, a sort of claustrophobia, but not that prominent, but since they are modern, they understand that their machinery requires shelter from rain, snow and wind, as well as requiring clean rooms to perform nanotechnology achievements, if any. Thus they do understand the need to go under the roof to work, yet they don't see the need of going under the roof to rest, communicate, bathe, toilet or sleep (both senses). When they need to be alone (or undisturbed), they produce a sort of a temporary habitat up in the trees, hide up there to do what they need to (mostly to sleep, of course), then come down to socialize again. Such a habitat can be reused, of course, and is certainly able to be recycled without any harm to the environment.

So, their cities look like patches of buildings aka industrial districts in our own cities, surrounded by a circle of roads, but every other part of the city is covered by high trees, that are both used as sleeping places, a means of travel over the roads used by whatever transportation they have invented, most likely railroads, and potentially as a food source, and some clear spots exist for socialization needs like trading, feasts or any other gathering. Public toilets and sewers might also exist, depending on the size of industry, as this kind of species won't accept overcrowding for quite a long time, history wise.

Equipment wise, I expect each of them to be of an ascetic type, or "omnia mea mecum porto", with a pool of equipment kept available for the public, together with maintenance, thus if a person needs something big, he goes to a local storage (barn, warehouse, whatever) where stuff just lays around, takes what he needs, then returns after use, and possibly tools up a replacement if the piece breaks. This won't cause them to be "off the sky" for too long, thus is tolerable. And personal belongings are nowhere to be stored, thus there's no need to make or keep stuff that's of no use.

Regarding power lines, water supply, sewers etc, these things should only connect to the industry, so everything is localized in there, together with recycling. This society should understand the need to keep the land intact, so they don't produce trash in quantities we do, also they give priority to cleaning facilities over polluting ones. So their waste processing systems are exceptional and exceeding the demand by a large margin, their industries are pretty small as the demand of all the species is not too large. Their farms might also be different, not crops but orchards that allow "hiding in the trees", and also allow placing them within the "cities" themselves, reducing the needs for transportation overall.

Also they might use food as money, meaning quite different financial system from ours, potentinally hindering their progress as a whole, but providing a useful balance in industry over agriculture, also being a decent counter for greed of a single specimen.

Finally, such a city is not possible without an altered mindset, because if you don't have a house, your "home" is a different entity, and the meaning of "mine" and "ours" also changes drastically. So if your species are of a different mindset than described, check if they are able to create a society, industry and cities, before inventing what their industry-driven city looks like.